# Bluemix Kubernetes docker deployment query

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-kubernetes

We tried using **Kubernetes** on **Bluemix**. We followed - https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_tutorials.html#cs_tutorials

Though the service is getting exposed and we do see the public ip address and NodePort we are not able to access the web page through public IP.

When we attach the container we do see that the *hello world Python Flask app* is working fine and we could access the web page locally at 5000 port.

Unfortunately it is not accessible over public IP address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that example, the default app is on port 8080, and the commands are all set to expose it through that.  Since you changed it to 5000 (otherwise it wouldn't work locally on that port), double check on the service definition to make sure it's looking at that port as well.

That's the `kubectl describe service yourservicename` command.

Also, to access it remotely over the node port, you'll come in through the port listed in that describe as "nodeport", not port 5000 - 5000 is the internal port, the "nodeport" is the external port.

Comment: I specified the port 5000 in run as well as in service creation and it worked ! Thanks you saved my day !

Answer (score 0):

Start by running `kubectl describe service` and `kubectl get service -o yaml` to determine if there were any problems during service creation.